# getting list items in SPFx application

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

trying to retrieve list items via get method of spHttpClient object in SPFx webpart project.

Here code piece;

```
private readItems(): void {
    this.setState({
      status: 'Loading all items...',
      items: []
    });
    this.props.httpClient.get(`${this.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id`, 
    SPHttpClientConfigurations.v1)
      .then((response: Response): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
        debugger;
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response: { value: IListItem[] }): void => {
        debugger;
        this.setState({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${response.value.length} items`,
          items: response.value
        });
      }, (error: any): void => {
        this.setState({
          status: 'Loading all items failed with error: ' + error,
          items: []
        });
      });
  }
```

when this function triggered here is the response from server;
[image]

Message is obvious, but I really need to get list items in this web address.
how can I achieve it ?

I created this project with yeoman generator("yo @microsoft/sharepoint") is there any configuration to make it run http:// instead of https://

as you know default address of application is "https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your SPFx webpart on the SPO workbench page as below:

```
https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx
```

Here, `https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html`is the local SharePoint Workbench page. Your code needs to run on the SharePoint Workbench page hosted in SharePoint.

On that page, you need to add your webpart (in my case, its the helloworld webpart) and configure the properties to get data from list.

[image]

To test in the local workbench you will need a mock store that returns mock data.

Create a new file inside the src\webparts\helloWorld folder named MockHttpClient.ts.

Copy the following code into MockHttpClient.ts:

```
import { ISPList } from './HelloWorldWebPart';

export default class MockHttpClient {

    private static _items: ISPList[] = [{ Title: 'Mock List', Id: '1' },
                                        { Title: 'Mock List 2', Id: '2' },
                                        { Title: 'Mock List 3', Id: '3' }];

    public static get(restUrl: string, options?: any): Promise<ISPList[]> {
    return new Promise<ISPList[]>((resolve) => {
            resolve(MockHttpClient._items);
        });
    }
}
```

Reference - [SPFX - Connect your client-side web part to SharePoint](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint)

Comment: hello can you help me about this post: "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205743/spfx-r-c-post-method-sphttpclient-configurations-v1-undefined-exception"

Answer (score 4):

**OPs Question was**: Is there any configuration to make it run http:// instead 
of https://

---

[image]

Means (for security reasons) you can't call an HTTP:// URI from a secure HTTPS:// site

**after** you recieved his error in the console;
there will be a button (*far left or right in the URL bar*) to override security and allow HTTP endpoints

[image]

You can now call HTTP:// endpoints, but only from ***Your*** **current Browser session**

You can't overrule this setting with code because that defeats the whole purpose of security